# Ajax request quoting

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, xmlhttprequest, nested, quoting

I am trying to send an Ajax request using the prototype framework that adds a new row to my table (existing) on success. 
I have already made successful requests with other functions but i can't get this one to work. I am sure **it has something to do with my quoting in the insert html (the nested quotes).**

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317107/javascript-function-not-get-called-when-arguments-from-php) question helped me out for my previous function but in this one the quoting is still more complex.

[this](http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/14475a5eaea9ac42) is a thread on inserting the html

```
new Ajax.Request('switch.php', {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: 'action=addHour&addday=' + addday + '&addhour=' + addhour + '&addminute=' + addminute + '',
    onSuccess: ($('tbl_' + addday + '').down('tr').insert({
        Bottom: "<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP><TD id='var_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "' value='" + addhour ":" + addminute + "'></TD><TD id='del_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "'><input type='button' value='Del' onClick='deleteHour(" + addhour + "" + addminute + ", " + addday + ")'></TD></TR>"
    }))
});
```

I am quite new to web development, if someone could point me in the right direction (some explanation about the quoting order) that would help a lot,

thx,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pumbaa was right about the onSuccess callback; it needs to be a function. Its a good practice to wrap your input fields in a form element. I saw what you were trying to do with the 'add' variables by putting a blank string between them, but if you make them strings first, you won't have to do that. That simplifies your code a bit. I rewrote your code to make it more readable.

```
new Ajax.Request('switch.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
        action: "addHour",
        addday: addday,
        addhour: addhour,
        addminute: addminute
    },
    onSuccess: function(e) {
        addday = addday.toString();
        addhour = addhour.toString();
        addminute = addminute.toString();

        $('tbl_' + addday).down('tr').insert({bottom: '<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>\
          <TD id="var_"' + addday + addhour + addminute + '" value="' + addhour + ":" + addminute + '"></TD>\
          <TD id="del_"' + addday + addhour + addminute + '">\
            <form>\
              <input type="button" value="Del" onClick="deleteHour(' + addhour + addminute + ', ' + addday + ')">\
            </form>\
          </TD>\
        </TR>'});
    }
});
```

Comment: thx, this is exactly what i was looking for. Although i didn't get the insertion to work yet (could you think of common mistakes?) this helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onSuccess` value should be a `function`. You're actually passing the result of a function invocation here. Your code is equivalent to

```
var os = ($('tbl_' + addday + '').down('tr').insert({
    Bottom: "<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP><TD id='var_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "' value='" + addhour ":" + addminute + "'></TD><TD id='del_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "'><input type='button' value='Del' onClick='deleteHour(" + addhour + "" + addminute + ", " + addday + ")'></TD></TR>"
}));
new Ajax.Request('switch.php', {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: 'action=addHour&addday=' + addday + '&addhour=' + addhour + '&addminute=' + addminute + '',
    onSuccess: os
});
```

That's not what you want. You probably want this:

```
var os = function () {
    $('tbl_' + addday + '').down('tr').insert({
        Bottom: "<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP><TD id='var_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "' value='" + addhour ":" + addminute + "'></TD><TD id='del_" + adday + "" + addhour + "" + addminute + "'><input type='button' value='Del' onClick='deleteHour(" + addhour + "" + addminute + ", " + addday + ")'></TD></TR>"
    });
};
new Ajax.Request('switch.php', {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: 'action=addHour&addday=' + addday + '&addhour=' + addhour + '&addminute=' + addminute + '',
    onSuccess: os
});
```

or directly:

```
new Ajax.Request('switch.php', {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: 'action=addHour&addday=' + addday + '&addhour=' + addhour + '&addminute=' + addminute + '',
    onSuccess: function () {
       $( // etc...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, pumba, thx for your input. altough your answer isn't exactly what i'm looking for....it is the right nested quoting for the html i want to insert that's blocking me, thx M.